# Adding content under jquery Datatables

Tags: jquery, html, datatables

I want to add content under my table that stays right under the tables content (so it moves right under the table depending on the amount of records shown).

Seems simple but for some reason whenever I add a  right after the table it doesn't seem to be moving up and down based on the tables content....

Comment: Hi! Would you be able to add your code or even better a JSFiddle with your code to the question? There is not a lot of content here to help us answer your question - https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Well it's the regular jquery datatables code. Right under the last </div> of my datatables code I place another <div> with position absolute but it stays static and doesn't move with my datatables content. I'll see if I can add my code.

Comment: Like is there a way to add to the footer part of datatables? So it would be right under the next page button at the bottom. Let's say something like a hyperlink right under the page button.

Comment: You can use the footer callback.  https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/footer_callback.html